# Alter table error code 1834

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter a table as follows. But I am receiving an Error Code:

> 1834 Cannot delete rows from table which is parent in a foreign key constraint 'downloads_ibfk' of table downloads.

```
ALTER TABLE users
MODIFY first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

Answer (score 6):

You obviously have a foreign key constraint blocking the ALTER TABLE.

You can deactivate the FK check by preceding your query with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

But remember to set it back to 1 after the query.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

By deactivating `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`, as suggested by @zonzon, you may get some unexpected results.
The error could also be due to the initial column schema and an incomplete `ALTER TABLE` query.

**If you have the same issue, here is how I fixed it:**

- My initial column schema was:

  ```sql
  # users.login | varchar(128) | collate utf8_bin | not null;
  ALTER TABLE users ADD login varchar(128) COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL;
  ```
- What I was trying to execute, **without success**:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN login login varchar(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
  # Cannot delete rows from table which is parent in a foreign key constraint '%s' of table '%s'
  ```
- What I have executed **with success**:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE Internaute CHANGE COLUMN login login varchar(128) COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL;
  # This query is more complete, I indicated the column's `COLLATE`. Otherwise the default collation is applied.
  ```

---

**Why my first query didn't work?**

In this query, I was also changing the collation (to the default one), so I think, my `ALTER TABLE` operation used the `COPY` algorithm to process my request.

Using this algorithm, a deletion is performed at some point. This is why you could get the error `Cannot delete rows from table ...` in an `ALTER TABLE` operation.

By default, the `ALTER TABLE` operations use other algorithms (`INSTANT` or `INPLACE`) that prevent the delete step. But, an `ALTER TABLE` operation that changes a column's collation is not supported by these other algorithms.

You can get [more information here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-performance) about the `ALTER TABLE` algorithms and their supported operations.